# regex changing $ char in preg replace

Tags: php, regex, replace

I need your help guys to replace $ as char.
It seems that $ is ending the line in preg replace and i want to replace "$" char to ";$"

I had made the code:

```
$search = array(
"/\$/",


    $replace = array(
";$",
    echo preg_replace($search,$replace,"example $variable to replace");
```

What i made wrong?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I just tested that `$` is not a problem at least in this case. It seems that the problem is with the string since \ is not properly specified: `"/\\$/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to RegexBuddy, the following should work:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\$/', ';$', $subject);
```

Your problem has to do with the [use of double quotes instead of single quotes](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) in your source string. Try

```
$result = preg_replace('/\$/', ';$', 'example $variable to replace');
```

to avoid variable interpolation in the source string. Or escape the `$` in your string:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\$/', ';$', "example \$variable to replace");
```

Comment: wooow  thank you very much guy     the problem solved byt Tim pietzcker    and my fail was becouse i use "/\$/", instead of '/\$/',

Answer (score 0):

`$result = preg_replace('/\$/', ';$', $subject);`